# DB model strategy to override field value

Tags: java, database, jpa, database-design

We have to store some dynamic configuration in JSON format in DB. There would be some default configuration, and it can be overriden per account. Can someone help me with the strategy to store such kind for data.

I have come up with following. If the accountConfig is null then look at defaultConfig.

**DefaultConfig table**

```
id, name,   config
1   name1   {x:12, y: 13}
2   name2   {y:10, z:100}
```

**AccountConfig table**

```
id, accountId, defaultConfigId, accountConfig, active
1   1000       1                null           false
2   1000       2                {y:11, z:111}   true
```

Should I have inheritance, or embedded entities? or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should just have an AccountConfiguration table and a Configuration table.

```
AccountConfiguration
--------------------
id
accountid
configurationid

Configuration
-------------
configurationid
name
configuration
```

Your default configuration values would be the front rows of the Configuration table and the overridden configuration values would be the later rows.  You can add a boolean column to the Configuration table if you need to identify overridden configurations.

This way, you always do a join to get the configuration.